# The sum of two random variables that switch forms probabilistically

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose I have two independent identically distributed random variables. The peculiar thing about them is that each can, probabilistically, take one of two forms:

With probability $p_{A_1}$ the first is a Normal random variable with mean of  $\mu_A$ and standard deviation of $\sigma_A$. Moreover, with probability $1 - p_{A_1}$ the first is a Normal random variable with mean of  $\mu_B$ and standard deviation of $\sigma_B$.

Simillarly,

With probability $p_{A_2}$ the second is a Normal random variable with mean of  $\mu_A$ and standard deviation of $\sigma_A$. Moreover, with probability $1 - p_{A_2}$ the second is a Normal random variable with mean of  $\mu_B$ and standard deviation of $\sigma_B$.

What is the distribution of the sum of the two random variables?

Comment: I don't see how comes they are identically distributed. Is $p_{A_1} = p_{A_2}$?

Comment: You may find this post useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174791/sum-of-gaussian-mixture-and-gaussian-scale-mixture.

Comment: pA1 is not generally equal to pA2